BoldReports ASP.NET Core
I'm trying to incorporate BoldReports into an ASP.NET Core web application. I get an error in the ReportViewerController and the method below. The error is "

Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I know that I have to instantiate the object and I'm assuming it's the ReportModel that's causing the error, but it's not an option in BoldReports.Web.
The error is thrown on the line here:
reportOption.ReportModel.DataSourceCredentials = new List<DataSourceCredentials> { dataSourceCredentials };


[NonAction]
public async Task OnInitReportOptions(ReportViewerOptions reportOption, string reportName, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
{
    string connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("SQLConnection");

    DataSourceCredentials dataSourceCredentials = new DataSourceCredentials
    {
        Name = "OrderWebDB",
        ConnectionString = connectionString,
    };

    reportOption.ReportModel.DataSourceCredentials = new List<DataSourceCredentials> { dataSourceCredentials };

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(reportName))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("ReportName is a required parameter.");
    }

    try
    {
        MemoryStream reportStream = await _reportService.PrepareReportStreamAsync(reportName, parameters);
        reportOption.ReportModel.Stream = reportStream;

        // Set report parameters
        List<ReportParameter> reportParameters = new List<BoldReports.Web.ReportParameter>();

        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
        {
            reportParameters.Add(new ReportParameter { Name = parameter.Key, Values = new List<string> { parameter.Value } });
        }

        reportOption.ReportModel.Parameters = reportParameters;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"Failed to generate the report: {ex.Message}", ex);
    }
}

